# Artifactory - turn off reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, artifactory

We had our Artifactory 4.4.0 server setup with Nginx reverse proxy.  Nginx was configured and in Artifactory the Admin - Configuration - Reverse Proxy form was filled out. Things were working properly.

We now no longer want to use Nginx reverse proxy but now the Web Server Type is locked in the Admin - Configuration - Reverse Proxy form and we are not able to reset or clear any data from the form - it forces mandatory fields to have data and saved or it reverts to it's original settings. If we disable Nginx, Artifactory is no longer able to access remote repositories and our builds fail.

How can the Nginx reverse proxy be 'unset' or turned off in Artifactory?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are saying that the screen:
'Admin --> Configuration --> reverse_proxy' is configured with Nginx and you wish to remove it from there. 
If this is indeed the case then 2 things:

1. This configuration is a template only. Meaning that it has no effect on your reverse proxy once or ever. This screen was created to assist Artifactory admins for generating proxy configuration, meaning that even if you see there Nginx configurations saved it doesn't mean that your server is behind Nginx.
2. In case that you still wish to remove it, although this has no effect on your system, you can do it as follows:PLEASE BE VERY CARFUL WHEN DOING THE BELOW:
   a. Go to: Admin --> Advanced --> Config Descriptor
   b. Copy all of the text and back it up outside of Artifactory (can be a txt document)
   c. Search for "reverseProxy"
   d. Delete the section of "" until ""
   e. Double check that you delete only this section, including the conf  and , and nothing else!
   f. Save.

This should clear the configuration template of the reverse proxy.